# What is the covariance matrix between AX and BY?

Tags: covariance

Let **X** = (X1, . . . , Xn) and **Y** = (Y1, . . . , Yn) be two random vectors (i.e.,
vectors of random variables). Suppose that the covariance between X_i and Y_j is G_ij . In
other words, the covariance matrix between the random vectors **X** and **Y** is **G**. Let **A** and
**B** be two n × n matrices. What is the covariance matrix between **AX** and **BY**?

edit:  by linearlity of expectation we know that E(**AX**) = **A**E(**X**) and E(**BY**) = **B**E(**Y**)

Comment: by linearlity of expectation we know that E(**AX**) = **A**E(**X**) and E(**BY**) = **B**E(**Y**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will treat $X$ and $Y$ as column vectors.

$G = \text{Cov}(X, Y) = E[(X-E[X])(Y-E[Y])^\top]$.

\begin{align}
\text{Cov}(AX, BY)
&= E[(AX-E[AX])(BY - E[BY])^\top]
\\
&= E[A(X-E[X])(Y-E[Y])^\top B^\top]
\\
&= A E[(X-E[X])(Y-E[Y])^\top] B^\top
\\
&= AGB^\top.
\end{align}