Understanding Gauss Markov Theorem proof
I am providing the proof ,need help in understanding few steps
Th :The best estimator of the estimable linear function $c'\beta$ of the parameters is $c'\hat{\beta}$,where $\hat{\beta_1},\hat{\beta_2},...,\hat{\beta_p}$ are the set of Least Square Estimators(LSE) of $\beta_1,\beta_2,...,\beta_p.$
Proof: Since $ c'\beta$ is estimable ,$\exists$ some $a$ $\ni$ $(X'X)a=c$
By Normal equations LSE of $c'\beta$ is given by $$c'\hat{\beta}=a'(X'X)\hat{\beta}=a'X'Y$$
Let $b'Y$ be any arbitrary linear unbiased estimator.Then $$c'\beta = E(b'Y) = b'X\beta \implies b'X = c' \equiv X'b = c$$
Now, $$\begin{align}
Var(b'Y) &= Var[{Xa+(b-Xa)}' Y]\\ & =Var(a'X'Y)+Var\{(b-Xa)'Y\}+2Cov\{a'X'Y,(b-Xa)'Y\}
\\ &=Var(a'X'Y)+Var\{(b-Xa)'Y)\}, \longrightarrow (1)[using (2)]
\\&\geq Var(a'X'Y)
\end{align}$$
since $$\begin{align}Cov\{a'X'Y,(b-Xa)'Y\}& =a'X'(b-Xa)\sigma^2 \longrightarrow (2) \\ &=a'(X'b-X'Xa)\sigma^2\\&= a'(c-c)\sigma^2 = 0 \end{align} $$
Can't Understand the steps marked by (2) ,specifically Can't understand why (b-Xa) is taken out instead of it's Transpose ?

Hi: It's important to understand the dimensions of the various vectors
and matrices in the formulation.
Note that $a^{\prime}$ is $1 \times p$ and $X^{\prime}$ is $p \times n$.
Also, $a^{\prime} X^{\prime}$ is a  $1 \times n$ vector and $b $ is $n \times 1$. Finally, $(b - Xa)^{\prime}$ is $1 \times n$.
Now, assume the general case where $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ are $1 \times n$  vectors and $Y$ is $n \times 1$. Suppose one wants to compute the covariance: $cov (G_{1} Y,G_{2} Y)$,
Then, calling this Theorem ML, $cov (G_{1} Y,G_{2} Y) = G_{1} G_{2} ^{\prime} \times Cov(Y)$.
I don't know what the proof of this is. Basically, I always just took it for granted because, otherwise, if the transpose of $G_2$ is not taken, then the matrix multiplication of the two vectors, $G_1$ and $G_2$, does not result in  a scalar. In fact, the multplication is not valid because of non-conforming
dimensions. Essentially the proof is that $E((G_{1} Y)(G_{2} Y))$ only makes sense if the multiplication of $G_1$ and $G_2$ can be carried
out.
Now, going back to the original example, we have :
$ Cov(a^{\prime} X^{\prime} Y, (b - Xa)^{\prime} Y) $
Recall from earlier that $a^{\prime} X^{\prime}$ is $ 1 \times n$ and $(b - Xa)^{\prime}$ is $1 \times n$. Therefore, since we have the same setup as in the Theorem ML, we can then use Theorem ML  here to obtain:
$ Cov(a^{\prime} X^{\prime} Y, (b - Xa)^{\prime} Y)  
= a^{\prime} X^{\prime} (b - Xa)^{\prime \prime} Cov(Y) = a^{\prime} X^{\prime}(b - Xa) Cov(Y) $

So as per the 'Th. ML' the vectors act like scalars with a rule that the traspose of G2 is taken out .
Can I get the fullname of the theorem you mentioned ,so that I an get deep into the topic . And thankyou sir for the explanation .

I'm sorry Akash but I was trying to add a little humor and clearly failed. ML stands for mark leeds so I was trying to be funny by saying "ML" theorem. Basically, I couldn't prove what I wanted to prove so I kind of fudged it sort of. Let me see if I can find something on the net that has a better proof than I gave.

As far as the answer goes, if you have two vectors of the same dimension ( in this case, $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ are both $1 \times n$ ), then, if you want to calculate $cov(G_{1}Y, G_{2} Y)$, this is equal to $G_{1} G_{2}^{\prime} var(Y)$. Why it is equal to that is kind of because if you want the first vector $G_1$ to multiply the second vector, $G_{2}$, only way  is by transposing $G_{2}$ to obtain $G_{1} \times G_{2}^{\prime}$. In your partocular case, taking the transpose of something that is already transposed, namely, $(b - Xa )^{\prime}$, so that you just come back to the original vector.

and my apologies for leading you astray. I'm trying to make up for that by finding something that is more helpful than my answer.

Akash: I found something which, IMHO, is much better than my attempt at an answer. I would read this whole document ( it's only 5 pages ) slowly and see if you can follow each line ( don' skip any) The actual derivation which seems to prove your question ( sort of anyway ) is on the top area of page 3. After you go through this document in full, feel free to ask questions about anything you don't understand related to what you asked originally. https://www.math.kent.edu/~reichel/courses/monte.carlo/alt4.7d.pdf I hope that it helps.

Akash: Just to be clear: The statement that I named the "ML " Theorem is not wrong. It's just more of a statement than a theorem and I'm kind of using a hand waving argument to prove it. But, if you go through that five page document that I linked to, ( top of page 3 is key ), you should be able to see why the transpose is used on $(b-aX)^{\prime}$.

Okay .Thanks a lot ,i will am going through the document...... and will be Back soon

Akash: I looked again because what you are asking doesn't require a 5 page document. That recommendation is a bit like shooting an ant with a cannon. So I found this thread and I believe that angryavian answers your question beautifully. When reading the answer, recall that a matrix is just a special case of a vector. So, you can easily apply his result to your problem since you have vectors.  I'm confident that it will be come clear once you read his answer. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4382922/what-is-the-covariance-matrix-between-ax-and-by
